# Kubectl is not letting me deleting anything - How do I delete all the current deployments?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, terminal, kubectl

I ran this command to create my pod:

```
kubectl run my-ngnix --image nginx
```

Now, I'm trying to delete the pod/deployment with the following command:

```
kubectl delete deployment my-nginx
```

The problem is that my terminal is telling me that is not possible. Since it couldn't found the right info.

```
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "my-nginx" not found
```

If ask for all, this is what I see:

```
 kubectl get all
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-ngnix   1/1     Running   0          27m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP   159m
root@aharo003:~# kubectl stop pods,services -l pod/m-ngnix
```

Does someone know what else should I have to do?

Comment: The error is because you didn't create a deployment, you created a pod. Pods and deployments are not synonymous or interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kubectl get all` shows you the resources you created

in this case it starts with the kind and the resource name.

You can easily type `kubectl delete pod/my-ngnix` to delete the pod. Your command `kubectl run my-ngnix --image nginx` created just the pod without a deployment.

Comment: One more thing to understand resource a bit better. Read about it in the kubernetes.io docs. It helps a lot to understand the resources and how to create them. If you want to check it via kubectl command you can use `kubectl api-resources`. It shows you all supported resources in your cluster. `kubectl explain deployment` describes and shows you the fields you have to set, to create a resource. You can also do `kubectl explain deployment.spec` and further. Follow the attribute paths...